# Most "pythonic" way of populating a nested indexed list from a flat list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a situation where I am generating a number of template nested lists with n organised elements where each number in the template corresponds to the index from a flat list of n values:

```
S =[[[2,4],[0,3]], [[1,5],[6,7]],[[10,9],[8,11],[13,12]]]
```

For each of these templates, the values inside them correspond to the index value from a flat list like so:

```
A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]
```

to get;

```
B = [[["c","e"],["a","d"]], [["b","f"],["g","h"]],[["k","j"],["i","l"],["n","m"]]]
```

How can I populate the structure S with the values from list A to get B, considering that:
- the values of list A can change in value but not in a number 
- the template can have any depth of nested structure of but will only use an index from A once as the example shown above.

I did this with the very ugly append unflatten function below that works if the depth of the template is not more then 3 levels. Is there a better way of accomplishing it using generators, yield so it works for any arbitrary depth of template.

Another solution I thought but couldn't implement is to set the template as a string with generated variables and then assigning the variables with new values using eval()

```
def unflatten(item, template):
    # works up to 3 levels of nested lists
    tree = []
    for el in template:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, str):
            tree.append([])
            for j, el2 in enumerate(el):
                if isinstance(el2, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el2, str):
                    tree[-1].append([])
                    for k, el3 in enumerate(el2):
                        if isinstance(el3, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el3, str):
                            tree[-1][-1].append([])
                        else:
                            tree[-1][-1].append(item[el3])
                else:
                    tree[-1].append(item[el2])
        else:
            tree.append(item[el])
    return tree
```

I need a better solution that can be employed to accomplish this when doing the above recursively and for n = 100's of organised elements.

#### UPDATE 1

The timing function I am using is this one:

```
def timethis(func):
    '''
    Decorator that reports the execution time.
    '''
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print(func.__name__, end-start)
        return result
    return wrapper
```

and I am wrapping the function suggested by @DocDrivin inside another to call it with a one-liner. Below it is my ugly append function.

```
@timethis
def unflatten(A, S):
    for i in range(100000):

        # making sure that you don't modify S
        rebuilt_list = copy.deepcopy(S)

        # create the mapping dict
        adict = {key: val for key, val in enumerate(A)}

        # the recursive worker function
        def worker(alist):

            for idx, entry in enumerate(alist):
                if isinstance(entry, list):
                    worker(entry)
                else:
                    # might be a good idea to catch key errors here
                    alist[idx] = adict[entry]

        #build list
        worker(rebuilt_list)

    return rebuilt_list

@timethis
def unflatten2(A, S):
    for i in range (100000):
        #up to level 3
        temp_tree = []
        for i, el in enumerate(S):
            if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, str):
                temp_tree.append([])
                for j, el2 in enumerate(el):
                    if isinstance(el2, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el2, str):
                        temp_tree[-1].append([])
                        for k, el3 in enumerate(el2):
                            if isinstance(el3, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el3, str):
                                temp_tree[-1][-1].append([])
                            else:
                                temp_tree[-1][-1].append(A[el3])
                    else:
                        temp_tree[-1].append(A[el2])
            else:
                temp_tree.append(A[el])
        return temp_tree
```

The recursive method is much better syntax, however, it is considerably slower then using the append method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use generators with recursion

```
A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]
S = [[[2,4],[0,3]], [[1,5],[6,7]],[[10,9],[8,11],[13,12]]]
A = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(A)}

def worker(alist):
    for e in alist:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            yield list(worker(e))
        else:
            yield A[e]

def do(alist):
    return list(worker(alist))
```

This is also a recursive approach, just ***avoiding individual item assignment*** and letting `list` do the work by reading the values "hot off the CPU" from your generator. If you want, you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVXLbtswEDybX0E4B0kAa0RSnwFy8LGHnnwUiECR1g1jmhQoOq1Q9NvdJUXbsiIHSXsogYVEarg7muGj6eyDVvlebBttLLViC8KS0FvvVGW1li0h7oOht6ehRVMaK0oZ91MWBhooLaP98zZnVO2292Bu02tsCSHb7q4Fu2swSRRFS3wU83LO5vcYFUaNARhrjO8YDxgC4xFjgyExthhqzsnKzS6KjL3nrLhmOecM@yn7gN2P7BN2sXfNvuDzM0tTfKQ5SzPOOXGFf21u6BNda0M3DF@EooBkwZQW4mXym9Swpj@02YCJSylam9yQmUODg/oRHJiJNRWtUK0tVQUxMHqAzmadAFn7fhzyQJLgB5AtDADLArgvVutTIYMiGXU2uf@WENSNEC9i2qt4MKrSTUecKv8gyt@7Udaisl5W6FDYUvbSQsd855m85IraB8CVUu1MK54gaN2vLaEVGRqggy6EYvNCYCX3v4saoHEvAdIjXGVR/2RY0pruvPZBYhrayEA34WgiHbSDhQ6QHL/0Xg5xPn@B1TlS9KIUfg7vqQVjPWpgZTa2UkrwMrT/z1FvwE6tZWktqCxeMroKolzhDraaSngCSXM/ZGHb3FkD4Grykw1owsj91WX1JRv@@uKrxRn3EhJaqpoqbcfg1pqRTUcai7JpQNVxwZMzgCP16Ehl56xAjjJN0cvexC@bIviMaPEu5ZfIDklvHOl8TDq7kH6Kff4m9vlL7Cf/4jV/Mr1pXp0WD0uZT6S@nHJSZ5cm4y9t42fryE0JM8IePkL6fYxXW6Vrt/wjPMlXSURc15/R4ew4jPnNPt5Y0b4xQtk4@tZhgXYn7U3E/FVs4pCa0cP1iddAQPfQ9IT1RdE6f0GMcdk5Lgu4LEn2@z8)-- `setup1` and `setup2` copied from @DocDriven 's answer (but I recommend you don't exaggerate with the numbers, do it locally if you want to play around).

Here are example time numbers:

```
My result: [0.11194685893133283, 0.11086182110011578, 0.11299032904207706]
result1: [1.0810202199500054, 1.046933784848079, 0.9381260159425437]
result2: [0.23467918601818383, 0.236218704842031, 0.22498539905063808]
```

Comment: Yes, this worked out perfectly and sped up the execution time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using recursion:

```
import copy

S =[[[2,4],[0,3]], [[1,5],[6,7]],[[10,9],[8,11],[13,12]]]

A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]

# making sure that you don't modify S
B = copy.deepcopy(S)

# create the mapping dict
adict = {key: val for key, val in enumerate(A)}

# the recursive worker function
def worker(alist):

    for idx, entry in enumerate(alist):
        if isinstance(entry, list):
            worker(entry)
        else:
            # might be a good idea to catch key errors here
            alist[idx] = adict[entry]

worker(B)
print(B)
```

This yields the following output for B:

```
[[['c', 'e'], ['a', 'd']], [['b', 'f'], ['g', 'h']], [['k', 'j'], ['i', 'l'], ['n', 'm']]]
```

I did not check if the list entry can actually be mapped with the dict, so you might want to add a check (marked the spot in the code).

**Small edit:** just saw that your desired output (probably) has a typo. Index 3 maps to "d", not to "c". You might want to edit that.

**Big edit:** To prove that my proposal is not as catastrophic as it seems at a first glance, I decided to include some code to test its runtime. Check this out:

```
import timeit

setup1 = '''
import copy

S =[[[2,4],[0,3]], [[1,5],[6,7]],[[10,9],[8,11],[13,12]]]
A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]
adict = {key: val for key, val in enumerate(A)}

# the recursive worker function

def worker(olist):

    alist = copy.deepcopy(olist)

    for idx, entry in enumerate(alist):
        if isinstance(entry, list):
            worker(entry)
        else:
            alist[idx] = adict[entry]

    return alist
'''

code1 = '''
worker(S)
'''

setup2 = '''
import collections

S =[[[2,4],[0,3]], [[1,5],[6,7]],[[10,9],[8,11],[13,12]]]
A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]

def unflatten2(A, S):
    #up to level 3
    temp_tree = []
    for i, el in enumerate(S):
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, str):
            temp_tree.append([])
            for j, el2 in enumerate(el):
                if isinstance(el2, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el2, str):
                    temp_tree[-1].append([])
                    for k, el3 in enumerate(el2):
                        if isinstance(el3, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el3, str):
                            temp_tree[-1][-1].append([])
                        else:
                            temp_tree[-1][-1].append(A[el3])
                else:
                    temp_tree[-1].append(A[el2])
        else:
            temp_tree.append(A[el])
    return temp_tree
'''

code2 = '''
unflatten2(A, S)
'''

print(f'Recursive func: { [i/10000 for i in timeit.repeat(setup = setup1, stmt = code1, repeat = 3, number = 10000)] }')
print(f'Original func: { [i/10000 for i in timeit.repeat(setup = setup2, stmt = code2, repeat = 3, number = 10000)] }')
```

I am using the timeit module to do my tests. When running this snippet, you will get an output similar to this:

```
Recursive func: [8.74395573977381e-05, 7.868373290111777e-05, 7.9051584698027e-05]
Original func: [3.548609419958666e-05, 3.537480780214537e-05, 3.501355930056888e-05]
```

These are the average times of 10000 iterations, and I decided to run it 3 times to show the fluctuation. As you can see, my function in this particular case is 2.22 to 2.50 times slower than the original, but still acceptable. The slowdown is probably due to using `deepcopy`.

Your test has some flaws, e.g. you redefine the mapping dict at every iteration. You wouldn't do that normally, instead you would give it as a param to the function after defining it once.

Comment: I marked this as a good solution because it is much cleaner and robust than the append method I provided, however, unless I am missing something is also considerably slower. 

I ran both methods on the same example for 100,000 times:

    `unflatten_recursion 3.8328068256378174sec

    unflatten_append 0.0009987354278564453sec
`

Comment: @Barus: That seems quite a lot. Can you post the code that you used to time it?

Comment: Added them in the original post, I included my current append function.

Comment: @Barus: I updated my answer. If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help. True I had your defn declared with every run, got similar results when I reran it with my @timethis decorator. I probably will substitute for your proposed method. However, I am still curious if this can be accomplished faster then my ugly append method. My concern for efficiency is due to this particular function being triggered multiple times in each iteration of an evolutionary solver, so it adds up.

Comment: @Barus: you might want to un-accept my answer then, so that other people can have a look at it and improve it.